# How do i Get Classes name of classes in entire solution in c#

Tags: c#

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\\ss\\Class1.cs");
```

i have a this type of code but i want to get "class name" like how many classes in my solution code will count the no of class and get the name by code in c#.

Comment: Do you want to enumerate all the classes in your solution? What does that have to do with ProcessStartInfo ?

Comment: well, shelling visual studio for each class file in the solution is certainly *not* the answer...

Comment: You need the file name or the class name that is used in the code ?

Comment: @ryadavilli yes i want to get name of the classes in my solution and my class name id Class1 and one more class is there Class2 so i just want to find out the ClassName by code in c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i am not wrong, you want to search all the classes that exist in the solution and get the class name.

Here is the pseudo code

1- Search all the solution for *.cs files.

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
```

2- Loop through all the *.cs files and search for the following pattern

```
namespace [WhatEver the name is]
{
    public class [Class Name]
```

Here is the code that you can use

```
foreach(string path in files)
{
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
    for (int i=0; i < lines.Count(); i++)
            {
                if(lines[i].ToLower().Contains("namespace"))
                {
                    int j = i + 2;
                    if(lines[j].ToLower().Contains("public class"))
                    {
                       string lClassname = lines[j].Replace("public class","");
                       //Save the class name here
                       break;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: This is a very naive approach. (1) There can be numerous namespaces (2) The class doesn't have to be directly one line under the namespace (3) Not all classes are public (4) c# has no consideration of lines, a statement can be spread across multiple lines.

Comment: Yes you right. I actually, followed this approach in one of my projects. I studied the whole structure of the application first. It worked. By the description, he can also use the above trick.

Comment: @Behroz which type of [FILE_NAME_HERE] i have to give ?

Comment: @Behroz i am getting an error on line "string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);" error is: Access to the path 'D:\ss' is denied. and i have given a correct path. so please help

Comment: @Behroz : i was wrong you are right and your code is running i am getting classes name thnks.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do will not involve `ProcessStartInfo`. There are two ways to approach this: if it is compiled, then load the assembly and use reflection to inspect the assembly (`someAssembly.GetTypes()` would be a good start). Alternatively, for inspecting *source code* (non-compiled), the Roslyn CTP can be used to load a project / solution / class file, and inspect the analysis tree.